# Immutable fields and lifetime mismatch

Tags: rust

Given this code (also [here](http://pastebin.com/qsCJ6Vi2)):

```
struct Vector2 {
    x: int,
    y: int
}

impl Vector2 {
    pub fn new(xs: int, ys: int) -> Vector2 {
        Vector2 { 
            x: xs,
            y: ys
        }
    }

    fn add(&self, otr: Vector2) -> &Vector2 { 
        self.x += otr.x; // cannot assign to immutable field (line 15)
        self.y += otr.y; // cannot assign to immutable field (line 16)
        return self; // lifetime mismatch                    (line 17)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec1 = Vector2::new(42, 12);
    println(fmt!("vec1 = [x: %?, y: %?]", vec1.x, vec1.y));

    let vec2 = Vector2::new(13, 34);
    println(fmt!("vec2 = [x: %?, y: %?]", vec2.x, vec2.y));

    let vec3 = vec1.add(vec2);
    println(fmt!("vec1 + vec2 = [x: %?, y: %?]", vec3.x, vec3.y))
}
```

I'm having issues with lines 15-17.

For lines 15 and 16, can someone explain what the best way to change those two variables would be? It seems I'm either not using `self` right or I'm missing a `mut` somewhere.

For line 17, it's giving me a `lifetime mismatch`, also saying:

> mismatched types: expected '&Vector2' but found '&Vector2'...the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 14:41 does not necessarily outlive the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the block at 14:41.

Does anyone know of any way to fix these two issues?

Comment: I have never used rust but if it is immutable then you should not try to mutate it. Create a new Vector2 in the add method and return that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to have `add` being a mutating operation, it should take `&mut self` rather than `&self`.

If you wish to have `add` create a new `Vector2`, then don't try mutating `self`—clone it (assuming 0.8-pre; on 0.7, you'd copy it instead with `copy self`) and modify the clone, or create a new instance with the same type. (This will be faster in a case like `add`.

While you're at it, don't just have a method called `add`: implement `std::ops::Add`, and `+` will work! (There is no `+=` yet—see https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/5992.)

The final code:

```
struct Vector2 {
    x: int,
    y: int,
}

impl Vector2 {
    pub fn new(x: int, y: int) -> Vector2 {
        Vector2 { 
            x: x,
            y: y,
        }
    }
}

impl Add<Vector2, Vector2> for Vector2 {
    fn add(&self, rhs: &Vector2) -> Vector2 {
        Vector2 {
            x: self.x + rhs.x,
            y: self.y + rhs.y,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec1 = Vector2::new(42, 12);
    println(fmt!("vec1 = %?", vec1));
    // 0.8-pre hint: use printfln!(...) instead of println(fmt!(...))

    let vec2 = Vector2::new(13, 34);
    println(fmt!("vec2 = %?", vec2));

    let vec3 = vec1 + vec2;
    println(fmt!("vec1 + vec2 = %?", vec3));
}
```

And its output:

```
vec1 = {x: 42, y: 12}
vec2 = {x: 13, y: 34}
vec1 + vec2 = {x: 55, y: 46}
```